# How to test a web application with jUnit/selenium from Jenkins that is deployed outside maven (in this very Jenkins)

Tags: maven, selenium, junit, jenkins

I have to test a webapp, that is build with maven from Jenkins as CI. The Jenkins instance deploys the webapp via script as 'post build step' to a test enviroment. After the deployment some integration tests should be fired and the results should go back to the jenkins instance.

I can't let maven itself deploy the webapp and utilize surefire/failsafe, because I am not allowed to do so.

I already have a little java app, that uses Selenium WebDriver to perform JUnit tests. I could run this app as 'post build step' like this:

```
java -cp /usr/share/java/junit.jar junit.textui.TestRunner [test class name]
```

but I have no ideas how to include dependecies (probably somehow like this: [Selenium Scripts on the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16234384/selenium-scripts-on-the-command-line)) and how to get the results back to Jenkins.

Comment: Can't you use two Jenkins jobs with dependencies between them? One to deploy and one to run the tests? I would also run the tests using Maven and not directly with Java. By the way, can you clarify why you cannot use Maven to deploy? (I would typically use `maven-cargo-plugin` here to deploy).

Comment: I can't use Maven deploy because that doesn't fall under my responsibility. Deploying is done by a different department, I could file an application and hope for the best. Curently I am really thinking of it, I could check how they deploy (they are making .rpm files and (maybe) other magic) and propose to let it be done by Maven and on top of it run my test inside maven.